# In method 'Solver_AddConstraint', argument 2 of type 'operations_research::Constraint *const'

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

> I am using following code to add constraint but getting TypeError: in method 'Solver_AddConstraint', argument 2 of type 'operations_research::Constraint *const'.

```
def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
    """Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
    from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
    #return distance_matrix[from_node][to_node]
    return multiply_with_mat[from_node][to_node]

transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)
....
second_cond = distance_value != 1000000.0
solver.Add(second_cond * transit_callback_index != 0)
```

> could you please help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: can you try `second_cond = (distance_value != 1000000.0).Var()`

Comment: I am getting AttributeError: 'numpy.bool_' object has no attribute 'Var' if using second_cond = (distance_value != 1000000.0).Var() @Laurent Perron

Comment: @Laurent Perron- I am using pywrapcp solver, this could create a problem for above adding constraint with "second_cond * transit_callback_index != 0" parameter.

Comment: The python API does not understand numpy object.   You need to cast it back to python.

Comment: @LaurentPerron- Actually that's not the real problem when i am using another condition variable like: first_cond = routing.NextVar(index) == next_next_node             
     second_cond = distance_value != 1000000.0
solver.Add(first_cond *second_cond * transit_callback_index != 0) then this code is running successfully. I don't understand why this is happening. If I want to use only second condition then how can we do that ?